# Any ideas on how to set/output something if the previous variant in a for loop has a parameter?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Realizing Twig can't escape a `for` loop, how would one go about setting a variable for the current item and not the following?

Scenario;
Color swatches are radio buttons, if default purchasable stock <= 0 and default purchasable unlimitedStock == false, the next radio button should be checked, and if this has stock <= 0 and so on, you get the idea, the next would be checked.

I can't seem to find a way to only check the next, and not all the following radio buttons if previous purchasable in the loop is out of stock.

A lot of checking of the checkers being checked here. Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that might be viable for your scenario:

```
{% set selected = false %}
{% for purchasable in product.variants %}
    {% if selected == false and (purchasable.stock > 0 or purchasable.unlimitedStock) %}
        {# output selected radio #}
        {% set selected = true %}
    {% else %}
        {# output unselected radio #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Essentially set a variable (`selected` in this case) that once set cannot be re-set, and is only set under the circumstances you mentioned (stock available or unlimitedStock set to true).

Comment: That did the trick perfectly! Can't believe how simple that was, borderline ashamed I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MN Twig Perversion](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-twig_perversion) plugin. It adds a `break` Twig tag, which allows you to escape from a loop once you have the data you need.

Comment: Trying to avoid adding too many plugins, but this seems useful nonetheless. Many thanks for the tip!